# Eclispe API - How to get parent project location

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface, eclipse-api

How to get the parent module of project. Here is my code works fine in Eclipse PDE.
But when I test the plugin(installing in eclipse) using test application by selecting the child module this condition **(if (projectRoot == selectedResource))** is coming true and it return src and target as child modules which is incorrect.
Any suggestion on how to get the parent module of project.

```
IResource selectedResource = Resource.getSelectedProject(); // this return selected module (F/parent/child1)
IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();  // \R
// this is not returning parent module??
IProject projectRoot = root.getProject(selectedResource.getProject().getName()); 
List<IResource> childModules = new ArrayList<>();

if (projectRoot == selectedResource) { // this is coming true (parent != child)
    IProject project = FileResource.getProject(selectedResource);
    childModules = Resource.getChildModules(project);
} else {
    childModules.add(selectedResource);
}
```

Resource.Class

```
private static IResource selectedResource;

public static void setSelectedResource(IResource resource) {
    selectedResource = resource;
 }

public static IResource getSelectedProject() {
    return selectedResource;
 }
```

Comment: What is "Resource" here?

Comment: @nitind current selected project

Comment: I meant its type.

Comment: @nitind type is IResource

Comment: `IResource` doesn't have a `getSelectedProject` method. What type is `Resource`?

Comment: @nitind updated the question Resource is a class

Comment: @greg-449 any suggestion on this ?

Comment: What do you mean by "module" - that is not a term that the Eclipse core APIs use.  Resources are only ever in one project and `getProject` on a project returns the same project so it is correct that `==` returns true.

Comment: @greg-449 Modules here mean subfolders. So, getProject is returning the same project,  how can I get root project ?

Comment: @greg-449 I want to compare parent location (P/parent) with selected project (F/parent/child1) location (projectRoot == selectedResource) This is coming true means my parent project is not set properly.

Comment: I mean for a given project how can I get the p/parent location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Eclipse workspace is organised like this:

```
IWorkspaceRoot
 - IProject
   - mixture of IFolder and IFile
 - IProject
   - mixture of IFolder and IFile
 - ... more IProjects
```

`IFolder` in turn can contain a mixture of more `IFolder` and `IFile` resources.

`IWorkspaceRoot`, `IProject`, and `IFolder` all extend `IContainer`. `IContainer` and `IFile` extend `IResource`.

The `IResource.getProject` method always returns the top `IProject` resource (except for `IWorkspaceRoot`).

`IResource.getParent` returns the immediate `IContainer` parent (null for `IWorkspaceRoot`)

So if you want the parent container of a resource call `IResource.getParent`, if you want the top level containing project call `IResource.getProject`.

Comment: Quick question here, so for a given project which has a submodule (defined in parent pom.xml) will that submodule is IProject or IFolder. For example below. Student //IProject and its submodule is Department will it be a Ifolder or IProject ?

Comment: maven modules are nothing whatsoever to do with Eclipse APIs, the are completely unrelated things. If you want to work with maven pom.xml so should use maven APIs.

Comment: Actually, I am testing my Eclipse API plugin in maven based project.

Comment: Fine, but that doesn't mean that the modules are related to IFolder/IProject at all. maven just sees file system folders, some of them might be IFolders, some might be IProjects.

Comment: Thaks for clarification Greg

Comment: @Maana IFolder/IProject type is general for all the project type and it is not specific to Maven projects. If you would like to filter the maven project type then you might have to write custom conditions to do so.

Comment: @Maana for further queries you can reach out to me through LinkedIn https://www.linkedin.com/in/subashjanarthanan/